# Android int to Int[] SimpleArc Loader (Color)

Tags: android, arrays, colors

I'm using this library but now i need to change color:

https://github.com/generic-leo/SimpleArcLoader

But it say:

[image]

```
Error:(120, 33) error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[]
```

How to convert Color int in int[]?

Comment: You are aware that a downvote is not the end of the world, not is it a personal insult, unlike "You are pathetic". Had you read the link I had posted, you would see that the idea is to make StackOverflow as search-engine-friendly as possible, which is done by adding text and not images. The **What to do next** section explains that you should transcribe the exeption details, which you have done, and thus I changed my downvote. Take it as an oppurtunity to learn how to write better questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R.color.colorPrimary` is a resource id not a color or int array, you should give it an array of RGB/ARGB colors

```
configuration.setColors(new int[] {ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary)});
```

Comment: where is your RGB color?

Comment: Where is your RGB?ARGB color? For your kind information ContextCompat.getColor() returns int color. Check it.

Comment: and you need a correction. configuration.setColors(new int[] {ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary)});.

Comment: ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary) gets the RGB/ARGB color defined in a colors.xml. What I commented on in your answer is that just providing R.color.colorPrimary without looking it up will give you a random color. E.g. looking up `android.R.color.white` using `ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.white)` gets you `0xFFFFFFFF (white)`, whereas just providing `android.R.color.white`, as in your example, gets you `0x106000B (green)`, since it's just a random id

Answer (score 1):

Create an Array of color

```
int [] colors = new int[]{R.color.colorPrimary};
```

Then set it to `configuration.setColors();` method like this

```
configuration.setColors(colors);
```

or just use like this

```
configuration.setColors(new int[]{R.color.colorPrimary, R.color.colorPrimaryDark, R.color.colorAccent});
```

Comment: That's not correct, the method expects RGB/ARGB values, not a color resource id

Comment: don't see the err?

Comment: Well R.color.colorPrimary is just a random int value defined at build time, ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimaryColor) is the actual color. Looking at the class he's using, it expects actual colors, not color ids